# Why did Captain Dallas not reprimand Ash for failing to spot the chestbuster?

Tags: alien-franchise

I always wondered why Captain Dallas never tore Ash a new one for failing to spot a parasite as big as the chestburster. Ash was also their medical officer after all. Maybe it was a plot device, but in Dallas's place, I would have been incensed and viewed him with suspicion and distrust thereafter.

Answer (score 6):

This issue is actually directly addressed in [***Alien: The Official Movie Novelization*** by Alan Dean Foster](https://titanbooks.com/7336-alien-the-official-movie-novelization/).

> "What's that thing?"
>
> Ripley was pointing at a portion of the slowly shifting internal scan.
>
> "The stain on his lungs?"
>
> "I don't see any 'stain'".
>
> Dallas studied the view.
>
> "Think I see what she means. Increase the magnification on the respiratory system, Ash".
>
> The science officer complied. Now the small blot that had caught Ripley's
> attention stood out clearly, a dark irregular patch overlaying Kane's
> chest cavity. It was completely opaque.
>
> "We didn't know that it's on his lungs".
>
> Ash fiddled with controls.
>
> "It could just as readily be a scanner malfunction, or a radiation-damaged section of the scanner lens. Happens all the time."
>
> "Try more power", Dallas demanded. "Let's see if we can't improve the resolution"
>
> Ash adjusted the instrumententation, but despite his best efforts the dark blotch remained just that: an unrelieved dark splotch.
>
> "I can't raise the intensity any further or he'll begin to suffer radiation damage".
>
> "I know". Dallas stared at the enigmatic dark blot

So either there is a genuine and conveniently useful scanner malfunction or Ash has enough knowledge of the medical scanners to fool Dallas and get his agreement that Ash is competent.

Later on when Ripley gripes at him he states that "I'm not a medical officer, Nostromo isn't big enough to rate one". He goes on to comment that he wishes the Nostromo was better equipped medically as there is no precedence for this situation and claims he wishes he was better qualified. So he has excuses and makes sure to air them to protect himself. Never the less Ripley remains suspicious of Ash.

Comment: i can't imagine a ship so far away and spending so much money on fuel would not swing another crew member who is a medical officer. humans should be the cheapest things.

Comment: @releseabe it doesn't make much sense does it but if we are looking for an in universe answer thats the stated one. it actually sounds to me like Foster was trying to plug a plot hole. In any case Ash knew what he was seeing and was obfuscating and on a normal mission where the ship goes point to point and everyone stays in hypersleep maybe they could just about get by without a dedicated doctor on board.

Answer (score -3):

Several reasons: 1) The chest-burster started tiny and grew much faster than any parasite Ash would have experience with; 2) the interaction between the face-hugger and the host was complex and life-threatening; when the face-hugger released its hold and died, everyone thought the crisis had passed; 3) it's mentioned that one of the face-hugger secretions interfered with their X-ray imaging, so the could never get a good look at what was happening inside.